# Error while connecting to MySQL 1064 (42000) While trying to insert

Tags: python, mysql

I'm new here and very new to Mysql and Python.  I am having a problem with this this insert statement:

```
query = "INSERT INTO {0} (date, open, high, low, close, volume, ivol, hvol) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s))".format(str.lower(contract.symbol))  

dd = [(20210325, 34.0, 34.03, 33.91, 33.96, 500850, 0, 0), (20210326, 34.57, 34.69, 34.14, 34.53, 480315, 0, 0)]

cursor.executemany(query, dd)
```

The error is:

```
Error while connecting to MySQL 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '),(20210326,34.57,34.69,34.14,34.53,480315,0,0))' at line 1
```

The table is created with this statement:

```
createquery = ("CREATE TABLE {0}( date INT(8) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, open DECIMAL(18,4) NOT NULL, high DECIMAL(18, 4) NOT NULL, low DECIMAL(18,4) NOT NULL, close DECIMAL(18,4) NOT NULL, volume BIGINT NOT NULL, ivol DECIMAL(18,4) NOT NULL,hvol DECIMAL(18,4) NOT NULL)").format(str.lower(contract.symbol))
```

I've spent a full day trying to figure this out.  Can anyone give me a pointer?

Comment: You have an extra ) in your code.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that.  Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `INSERT` statement has one too many `)` at the end:

```
query = "INSERT INTO {0} (date, open, high, low, close, volume, ivol, hvol) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s))".format(str.lower(contract.symbol))
```

Should be:

```
query = "INSERT INTO {0} (date, open, high, low, close, volume, ivol, hvol) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)".format(str.lower(contract.symbol))
```